# Geemap: How to export a map that I can create with addlayer in a geolocalized tiff file with Jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, geemap

I get the map I want as a layer but I do not know how to extract the SAME map geolocalized. I only managed to create a html file but it is not really useful.

dataset is a imagecollection

m.add_layer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB') => This is what I need to export

Thanks a lot for any help

Laurent

To export a tif image from a map created in jupyter lab using Geemap library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.